# I am trying to substract one column from another to get the difference between the column. I am getting "‘-’ not meaningful for factors" error

Tags: r, dplyr

The following is my data (controlT1)

```
 T1 Temp   L1   L2    L3    L4    L5    L6    L7
1   1C   17 7,58 8,68 11,19 13,07 14,08 15,61 17,39
2   2C   17 6,04 6,01  7,67 10,83 12,46  15,1 17,05
3   3C   17 7,53 7,83  10,8  13,1 14,65 15,72 17,22
4   4C   17 6,38 6,97  8,87 10,91 12,66 14,48 16,37
5   5C   17 6,65 7,28  8,75 10,71 11,61 13,49 15,36
6   6C   17 6,39  7,2  9,56 11,86 12,52 15,47 17,15
7   7C   17 6,01 6,53  8,91 11,02 13,44 15,88 18,02
8   8C   17 9,03 9,64 10,87 12,45 13,87 15,05 15,97
9   9C   17 7,71 8,08 10,23 13,45 15,01 16,54 17,75
10 10C   17 6,05 6,62  9,49 12,03 14,02 16,26 17,43
```

I converted L1 and L2 using as.numeric() and did this :

```
Difference <- as.numeric(controlT1$L2-controlT1$L1)
```

This converts it to numeric and gets rid of the decimal point. I want the following :

I want the difference between L2-L1, L4-L3 and so on and want them stored in a new column.

Comment: controlT1 <- controlT1 %>% 
      mutate(c=controlT1$L2-controlT1$L1) I also tried this

Comment: It's better to share data in a `dput()` format so we can see exactly how the data is stored. It looks like your data was read in a factor values. How did you initially import this data? By default R expects `.` to be the decimal indicator for numbers, but there are options to read in data that uses `,` instead. If you change that during import, then everything should be read as numeric and you should be able to do the subtraction without a problem.

Comment: If you used `read.table` or `read.csv` to read in the data, I suggest either you add `dec=","` to its arguments, or perhaps use `read.csv2` that correctly handles the use of `,` (comma) as a decimal mark. I recommend fixing the problem at initial data import instead of post-import processing (including `as.numeric`), though that's certainly an option when in a rush ... for instance, `dat[-(1:3)] <- lapply(dat[-(1:3)], function(z) as.numeric(sub(",", ".", z)))` might work as a temporary patch.

Comment: @MrFlick I did use . to input. I am only noticing now that it is showing , in all of the data when I export it to R. On the csv file it is still . and not ,